# Assets\Scripts\EnemyAI.cs(49,13): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.Vector3' to 'bool'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently working on a FPS game and working on an Enemy AI script, but its showing an error on 17. I don't know exactly what the issue is; the error expands through lines 49-13, but I only declare bool on three lines in the Script.

'''

using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class EnemyAI : MonoBehaviour
{
public NavMeshAgent agent;

```
public Transform player;

public LayerMask whatIsGround, whatIsPlayer;

public float health;

//Patroling
public Vector3 walkPoint;
bool walkPointSet;
public float walkPointRange;

//Attacking
public float timeBetweenAttacks;
bool alreadyAttacked;
public GameObject projectile;

//Stats
public float sightRange, attackRange; 
public bool playerInSightRange, playerInAttackRange;

private void Awake()
{
    player = GameObject.Find("Player 2").transform;
    agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
}
private void Update()
{
    //CHeck for sight and attack range
    playerInSightRange = Physics.CheckSphere(transform.position, sightRange, whatIsPlayer);
    playerInAttackRange = Physics.CheckSphere(transform.position, attackRange, whatIsPlayer);

    if (!playerInSightRange && !playerInAttackRange) Patroling();
    if (playerInSightRange && !playerInAttackRange) ChasePlayer();
    if (playerInAttackRange && !playerInSightRange) AttackPlayer();
}

private void Patroling()
{
    if (!walkPointSet) SearchWalkPoint();

    if (walkPoint)
        agent.SetDestination(walkPoint);

        Vector3 distanceToWalkPoint = transform.position - walkPoint;

        //walkpoint reached
        if ( distanceToWalkPoint.magnitude < 1f)
            walkPointSet = false;
}

private void SearchWalkPoint()
{
    //Calculate random point in range
    float randomZ = Random.Range(-walkPointRange, walkPointRange);
    float randomX = Random.Range(-walkPointRange,walkPointRange);

    walkPoint = new Vector3(transform.position.x + randomX, transform.position.y, transform.position.z + randomZ);

    if (Physics.Raycast(walkPoint, -transform.up, 2f, whatIsGround))
        walkPointSet = true;
}

private void ChasePlayer()
{
    agent.SetDestination(player.position);
}

private void AttackPlayer()
{
    //Make sure enemy doesn't move
    agent.SetDestination(transform.position);

    transform.LookAt(player);

    if(!alreadyAttacked)
    {
        //Atack code here
        Rigidbody rb = Instantiate(projectile, transform.position, Quaternion.identity).GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        rb.AddForce(transform.forward * 32f, ForceMode.Impulse);
        rb.AddForce(transform.up * 8f, ForceMode.Impulse);

        ///
        alreadyAttacked = true;
        Invoke(nameof(ResetAttack), timeBetweenAttacks);
    }
}

private void ResetAttack()
{
    alreadyAttacked = false;
}

public void TakeDamage(int damage)
{
    health -= damage;

    if (health <= 0) Invoke(nameof(DestroyEnemy), .5f);
}

private void DestroyEnemy()
{
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
private void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
{
    Gizmos.color = Color.red;
    Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(transform.position, attackRange);
    Gizmos.color = Color.yellow;
    Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(transform.position, sightRange);
}
```

}

'''

I tried editing the bool states by declaring it as a public state but that did nothing to get rid of the error, I'm still green with coding since I'm a bit more used to making racing games and not FPS games.

Comment: What exactly did you expect "if (walkPoint)" to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would have been great If you had pointed out the exact line that gives the error, but I am guessing this is the issue.
The below line has an issue. `walkPoint` is of type `Vector3`.

```
if (walkPoint)
    agent.SetDestination(walkPoint);
```

you need to change to the below.

```
if (walkPoint != Vector3.zero)
    agent.SetDestination(walkPoint);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm pretty new at this level of coding since I started designing and programming my own games last year in the fall term of my courses. The element you provided did in fact help resolve the issue.

Comment: @UrielSamano Then mark his answer as Accepted,  please!